# Adding a scope to a rails 3 app upsets Devise variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Devise to authenticate. Its variable "current_user" is used widely in the app with no problem. Then I added the following scope in a model named "Answer"

```
scope :user_answers, where (:user_id => current_user.id)
```

The result of this scope is part of another scope in a model named "Question"

```
scope :qs_w_user_ans, joins(:questions) & Answer.user_answers
```

Since then, i get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user'
```

Why would that happen?

Thanks.

Comment: `current_user` is not available to the model layer (it is available for controller and views). It is not a good idea to add a dependency to the user in the model.

Comment: Hello, @Zabba. I Googled several variations of rails dependency user model and came up with nothing. Is it a security issue? Is there an article you can reference? or an explanation would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Zabba mentioned, you cannot access `current_user` in your model. You can pass an argument into your scope though:

```
scope :user_answers, lambda {|user_id| where(:user_id => user_id)}
```

Then you can call the scope like so (assuming you are calling this from a controller or view):

```
Answer.user_answers(current_user.id)
```

**Update**

I haven't tried this before, but I imagine you could do something like the following:

```
scope :qs_w_user_ans, lambda {|user_id| joins(:questions) & Answer.user_answers(user_id)}
```

You would have to wrap the outer scope with a lambda and pass in `current_user.id` when you call `qs_w_user_ans`. Then the user_id from that lambda is passed to `user_answers`, which itself uses a lambda to receive that argument. Try this out with my previous answer (two lambdas total).

Comment: Hey, McStretch... i should probably be paying you to write this code :=]. That is a great solution, except for the fact that user_answers is then part of another scope (see revised question above). I tried copying and pasting several variations of the above... as yet no joy.

Comment: lol no worries Jay, I'm glad these are all things I'm familiar with. I recently went through all this pain when learning Rails for the first time. I'll update my answer with a solution that should get you want you want.

Comment: I'll give it a go tomorrow and then post the results here.

Comment: @McStretch, @questions = Question.qs_w_user_ans(current_user.id) is in a controller for one of my views. The error i get is, "Association named 'questions' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?" I attempted accessing from the console and get, "undefined local variable or method `current_user'." So apparently in addition to models, "current_user" is not available to the console either.

Comment: @McStretch, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884132/why-is-devise-current-user-not-available-at-the-model-layer

Comment: @McStretch, if you are interested, i found this: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models

Comment: @Jay, thanks for the links. Actually the reason you're getting the association error in the controller is because you're joining :questions in Question. Question doesn't have a collection :questions - User does. It looks like this outer scope should be moved to the User model.

Comment: I get it. However it produces the same msg: "Association named 'questions' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?" Going to throw this into a new post.

Comment: @Jay, you'd need to add has_many :questions to your User model (right now it only has :answers). Is that something that would fit into your design, or would that not make as much sense?

Comment: @McStretch, yeah... the questions are static and not connected to users.