# Why is Devise's "current_user" not available at the model layer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

There are many posts about Devise and the lack of availability of "current_user" for use in models. There are numerous work arounds posted here and elsewhere. However, i haven't found the answer to "why" in any of the posts. Is this a security issue? If not, why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you don't have access to a session variable inside a model, it's not a Devise issue or something related to security. It's related to the MVC pattern used in Rails.

Comment: This answer +1. And ofcourse if you want to access it in your model... you can pass it as an argument. object.method(current_user)